# How can I wrap checkbox form elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, drupal, ubercart

I am working on some code that presents a form with a number of checkboxes.  I would like to get the checkboxes to wrap to a second (and third, and fourth) line, but am having trouble doing so.  At the moment, the checkboxes run straight off the page in a line without wrapping.

There are 10 (or more) checkboxes, but for the sake of brevity I've listed only a few of them since listing all of them wouldn't really add to the conversation:

My CSS:

```
.add-to-cart .attribute label {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 35px;
}
.add-to-cart .form-checkboxes{
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.add-to-cart .attribute .form-item .form-type-checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: bold 10px verdana, arial, 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

My HTML/Code:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <form class="ajax-cart-submit-form" action="/this-product" method="post" id="uc-product-add-to-cart-form-7" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="attribute attribute-7 even">
        <div class="form-item form-type-checkboxes form-item-attributes-7">
            <label for="edit-attributes-7">Extras </label>
            <div id="edit-attributes-7" class="form-checkboxes">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-attributes-7-49">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="edit-attributes-7-49" name="attributes[7][49]" value="49" class="form-checkbox" />
                    <label class="option" for="edit-attributes-7-49"> Blue </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-attributes-7-43">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="edit-attributes-7-43" name="attributes[7][43]" value="43" class="form-checkbox" />
                    <label class="option" for="edit-attributes-7-43"> Red </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-attributes-7-50">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="edit-attributes-7-50" name="attributes[7][50]" value="50" class="form-checkbox" />
                    <label class="option" for="edit-attributes-7-50"> Green </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *wrap to a second (and third, and fourth) line* this line is very confusing, please explain your post further

Comment: Currently the checkboxes run in a single row right off the web page and out of the container completely. I want them to wrap inside the container so they create multiple rows instead of one long row....does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.add-to-cart .attribute label {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 35px;
}
.add-to-cart .form-checkboxes{
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.add-to-cart .attribute .form-checkboxes:not(.form-item) {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: bold 10px verdana, arial, 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/91r7v20q/

Comment: No dice - it made the checkbox row float out of the form so the submit button below that row went to being underneath the row of checkboxes.

Comment: Where are button?

Comment: The submit button is in the next row, but really wasn't relevant to the problem so I left the code for that out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.  I changed this CSS code:

```
.add-to-cart .form-checkboxes{
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

To this:

```
.add-to-cart .form-checkboxes{
    max-width: 600px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I removed the fixed height to allow the block to be flexible in allowing the elements to be completely displayed before the last row (with the submit button, see comments on this questions).  Whew!